# Changing to 'follow-up' intent based on entity value in Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

I've an intent 'Setup' that has two followup intents 'Android' and 'IOS'.

The intent 'Setup' has an entity - deviceType - which is 'Required' and has a prompt (Can you tell me the device type?). Note - this intent does not have any 'responses'.

When the user says, 'How do I setup your app?', entity's prompt gets triggered and the user says - Ios / android. Now, based on this device type value, can I route the conversation to one of the followup intents?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a webhook, you should be able to use an if statement to change the intent response based on the entity that was used by the user. Something like this.

```
if(iosEntity) {
  conv.contexts.set("ios", 1);

  return conv.ask("Ios response");
} else {
  conv.contexts.set("android", 1);

  return conv.ask("Android Response");
};
```

It isn't really changing to the "fallback intent", but it would allow you to change output based on the entity.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious if the user device type is able to be detected? If so, asking this question will invite potential conflicting response, and enable ios settings on Android and vice versa. I'm sorry not answering but asking another question - I feel it's more efficient than posting a new question.